# how to obtain the value for $u(1,1)$ using $u\to e^x$...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,y)$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem $x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-y^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ as $u\to e^x$ as $y\to \infty$ then $u(1,1)=?$

(1)$-1$

(2) $0$

(3) $e^{-2\pi}$

(4) $1$

I know the auxillary quations here as $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-y^2}=\frac{dz}{0}$.

Using $\frac{dz}{0}$, I got $z=c_1$

and then using $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-y^2}$, and integrating I got

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}-\frac{1}{x}&=\frac{1}{y}+c_2\\\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}&=c_2\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

so, I got two solutions , I can write as $\phi(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})=z$ or $\phi(z)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$, but what to do further...How to use $u\to e^x$ and obtain $u(1,1)$, not getting...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is $u(x,y)=\phi(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}).......(*)$
Now $u\rightarrow e^x$ as $y\rightarrow \infty$ gives $e^x=\phi(1/x)$. On assuming $1/x=t$, it reduces to $\phi(t)=e^{1/t}$.
Thus $(*)$ reduces to $u(x,y)=e^{\frac{1}{\left (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right )}}=e^{\frac{xy}{x+y}}$ as the final solution.